# Git fatal: the remote end hung up when cloning JSONKit.git

Tags: git, github, git-clone, jsonkit

**What I Want**

I want to clone the [JSONKit repo](https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit) from Github.

**The Problem**

```
  % git clone git://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit.git                                                                                                                            
    Cloning into JSONKit...
    fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

**What I've Tried**

- Cloning another read only repo

  ```
  git clone git://github.com/kgn/KGNoise.git
  ```

For example, works perfectly.

**Other Details**

My git version is 1.7.5.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with the https github address:

```
git clone https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit.git
```

If the case is correct, the git address should work, unless it failed on a side effect of (5-6 October):

> A small percentage of git repositories are unavailable due to a heavily loaded fileserver pair.

The [OP John Gallagher](https://stackoverflow.com/users/60131/john-gallagher) [confirms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12768490/git-fatal-the-remote-end-hung-up-when-cloning-jsonkit-git/12776921#comment17290729_12776921) it was a side-effect of that incident, so, as a general rule, when a GitHub repos host provider displays a:

```
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

It is probably caused by an incident in their infrastructure.
(If not, then and only then the repo itself might have an issue)

Comment: Turned out to be the latter problem. It works now. Thanks for the answer!